# Change of order in operation derivatives over time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a really dumb question probably but i can't get my head around it.

my question is,with a generic function $x(t)$
is it possible to do this:

$${-\frac{\dot{x^2}}{x^4}} = ({\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{x}})^2$$

I can't see the problem with what would be wrong with this,

could someone help me in my confusion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt to handling with this:

First of all, I will simplify the term on the right.
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{x}=\dot{x} \cdot (-1) \frac{1}{x^2}=-\frac{\dot{x}}{x^2}$$
Next, I will simplify the term on the left.
$$-\frac{\dot{x}^2}{x^4}=-\left(\frac{\dot{x}}{x^2}\right)^2$$
Plugging in, we get the following:
$$-\left(\frac{\dot{x}}{x^2}\right)^2=\left(-\frac{\dot{x}}{x^2}\right)^2 \\
-\left(\frac{\dot{x}}{x^2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\dot{x}}{x^2}\right)^2
$$

Obviously this only holds if the part inside the brackets is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\left (\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{x}\right )^{2} =\left ( -\frac{\dot{x}}{x^{2}}\right )^{2}$$ =\frac{\dot{x}^{2}}{x^{4}}$. So you can not do what you want.